# python3.x regex split chops off first character

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Not sure whats wrong with my regex expressions or why its chopping off the first character. The regex correctly IDs what i want to split on, but why is the first character missing in each element of the array?

```
>>> f = "value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http/ssoeproxy/logout    value: http://ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:user-services-http-two/ssoeproxy/logout    value: user-services-http #458930               value: user-services-http-two #458930"
>>> re.split(r'[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?', f)
>>> ['', 'alue', ': ', 'ttp', '://', 'c2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', '.', 'ompute-1', '.', 'mazonaws', '.', 'om', ':', 'ser-services-http', '/', 'soeproxy', '/', 'ogout', '    ', 'alue', ': ', 'ttp', '://', 'c2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx', '.', 'ompute-1', '.', 'mazonaws', '.', 'om', ':', 'ser-services-http-two', '/', 'soeproxy', '/', 'ogout', '    ', 'alue', ': ', 'ser-services-http', ' #', '58930', '               ', 'alue', ': ', 'ser-services-http-two', ' #', '58930', '']
```

Comment: Your parentheses are out of place.

Comment: `([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?`

Comment: Try with `([a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)`

Answer (score 1):

A more detailed explanation of your problem here is that `split()` will split on whatever group you're capturing if you only specify one capture group. It won't split on your whole regular expression. In this case you're capturing everything but the first letter. `[a-z0-9]` is outside your parentheses. Move your parentheses to include this part and you're good to go.